# Translating website to Arabic dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, html, css, dom, arabic

I am facing a pesky problem at the moment on a large website with multiple languages. On arrival at the website, it detects what country you are from and prompts you to confirm this. On confirmation, it swaps out the pages languages from the DB and displays the relevant language. This is done using jQuery. Now the problem is that Arabic reads rtl, so I need to either:

-- swap out the stylesheets for "rtl" version

or

-- change the HTML tag and include a "dir='rtl'" arrtribute

Now, I have tried both of these, with failures on both. When I view the page source, it still shows the old Css file or HTML tag without the "dir" attribute. Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe this to be due to the DOM not registering the new changes, as they have happened asynchronously via jQuery after the DOM has been instantiated.

After all that blah blah and tldr;
Is there not an easier way to swap out the text direction dynamically? If this is a DOM issue, how can I reload the DOM after the asynchronous callback?

 I have been at this issue for hours now and have had very little luck on the interwebz.

Any and all help is welcome and greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

William Francis

EDIT:

After much investigation I found that the only way to truly work the Arabic way is with a post-back. Once the language has been selected you do a postback, then its just a simple process of changing the Stylesheet HREF attribute from code behind. There doesn't seem to be any form of JavaScript or jQuery that can change it without a post-back and still reflect the new Stylesheet. NOTE: you need to set the Stylesheet HREF on each post-back, i.e. through a master page. The Stylsheet changes do not persist across pages.

Here's a website that helped greatly and explains a whole lot on Stylesheet changes using JavaScript. sadly, it didn't work for me.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/

Answer (score 0):

There could be several things going on.  I found this page to be very helpful when I was dealing with a similar thing, so I highly recommend it:

http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/

Also, if you aren't already doing so, use a tool like Firebug to examine the generated DOM after your AJAX has run to be sure you are seeing the altered state of the DOM and not the initial source of the page.  It *is* possible to change the dir dynamically--you can use Firebug to add a new attribute to the HTML tag of this very page (set dir="rtl") to see it change dynamically.  It could be some other element is overriding the direction, it could be that the AJAX changes aren't loading correctly, or other things.  If you can post more of your code it would be helpful to give a better answer, but I hope this will help.